# When I set gravity of Edittext to Center, placeHolder isnot visible

Tags: android, android-widget, android-edittext

I set the gravity of `Edittext` to CENTER, when I run it, the `placeholder` can be seen but when I try to set Ellipsize it cannot be seen. I have this issue on Sony Xperia mini`(API level 7)`. With other phones it seems fine. 
Here's the code:

```
    edittext =    (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    edittext.setHint("PlaceHolder");   
    edittext.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    edittext.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.START);`
```

Comment: which are the other components on screen... please post full code..

Comment: edittext is the only component on the screen. And it doesnot matter if I set it in xml or not.